# Finding sides using trigonometry.

Tags: trigonometry

I am currently studying for a maths exam and I came upon a question with this diagram [image]
 With the question asking to solve all of the variables. No other information was given. How is this possible? Assume the triangles are right angle triangles.

Comment: Watch out with those screenshots dude (read about U.S. congressional candidate Mike Webb)!

Comment: Added a more clear diagram.

Comment: @barakmanos hahahaha +1

Comment: If you pick any $r,s$ then $a,b$ are fixed. You can then get the required 30 overlap by adjusting the distance between the poles. So there is no way of determining $r,s$ (or $a,b$) without more information.